# How to design a database schema with type and subtype

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I've read plenty of supertype/subtype threads and I'm pretty sure I am not asking the same one.

I have the following tables in my database. Note that:
1. Some security types only need Type but require no SubType, such as stocks and bonds.
2. Securties.TypeId is a foreign key pointing to Type.ID.
3. Securties.SubTypeId has no foreign key relationship to BondType or DerivativeType tables. And currently the data integrity is maintained by C# code.

Since lacking of foreign key relationship is bad, I want to refactor this DB to have it. Given that this DB is already in production, what's the best way to improve it while limiting the software risk? i.e., one way to do it is to combine all XXXType tables into a single table and have all SubTypeIds rearranged, but clearly that involves updating tons of records in the Securites table. So it's considered a more risky approach than another one which doesn't require changing values.

```
[Securites]
ID     Name         TypeId     SubTypeId
 1     Stock1       2          NULL
 2     Fund1        3          NULL
 3     Bond1        1          3
 4     Deriv1       4          3


[Type]
ID     Name
 1     Bond
 2     Stock
 3     ETF
 4     Derivative

[BondType]
ID     Name
 ...
 2     GovermentBond
 3     CorporateBond
 4     MunicipalBond
 ...

[DerivativeType]
ID     Name
 ...
 2     Future
 3     Option
 4     Swap
 ...
```

Comment: Put all of the subtypes in one table with unique subTypeIDs and a TypeID column that indicates what Type each SubType is.  Then change your [Securities] table to only have a subTypeID.

Comment: Why is updating existing column values (to fit a new schema) risky? Not sure how you propose to change a database schema without migrating existing data.

Comment: Thanks, @RBarryYoung and EkoostikMartin. The reason we want to keep the existing SubTypeId values the same is because there are many code built around them, e.g., we also have enums and hard coded code that refer to these Ids. I'll check with my manager tomorrow but I think that's mostly the reason he voted against a approach similar to  RBarryYoung 's in the first place.

Comment: You should def check out Ch 20 (Banking) of Enterprise Model Patterns by Hay